# Symfony2 - PdfBundle not working

Tags: php, symfony, pdf-generation, twig

Using Symfony2 and [PdfBundle](https://github.com/psliwa/PdfBundle) to generate dynamically PDF files, I don't get to generate the files indeed.

Following documentation instructions, I have set up all the bundle thing:

autoload.php:

```
'Ps' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
'PHPPdf' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/PHPPdf/lib',
'Imagine' => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/PHPPdf/lib', __DIR__.'/../vendor/PHPPdf/lib/vendor/Imagine/lib'),
'Zend' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/PHPPdf/lib/vendor/Zend/library',
'ZendPdf' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/PHPPdf/lib/vendor/ZendPdf/library',
```

AppKernel.php:

> ...
>       new Ps\PdfBundle\PsPdfBundle(),
>       ...

I guess all the setting up is correctly configured, as I am not getting any "library not found" nor anything on that way...

So, after all that, I am doing this in the controller:

```
...
use Ps\PdfBundle\Annotation\Pdf;
...

/**
 * @Pdf()
 * @Route ("/pdf", name="_pdf")
 * @Template()
 */
public function generateInvoicePDFAction($name = 'Pedro')
{
    return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Shop:generateInvoice.pdf.twig', array(
        'name' => $name,
    ));
}
```

And having this twig file:

```
<pdf>
    <dynamic-page>
        Hello {{ name }}!
    </dynamic-page>
</pdf>
```

Well. Somehow, what I just get in my page is just the normal html generated as if it was a normal Response rendering.

The `Pdf()` annotation is supposed to give the "special" behavior of creating the PDF file instead of rendering normal HTML.

So, having the above code, when I request the route `http://www.mysite.com/*...*/pdf`, all what I get is the following HTML rendered:

```
<pdf>
    <dynamic-page>
        Hello Pedro!
    </dynamic-page>
</pdf>
```

(so a blank HTML page with just the words `Hello Pedro!` on it.

Any clue? Am I doing anything wrong? Is it mandatory to have the alternative *.html.twig apart from the *.pdf.twig version? I don't think so... :(

Comment: Removing my old answer as it wasn't a solution. The bundle on github includes some examples, do those work for you?

Comment: Well, your answer was valid indeed ;), as I hadn't described the configuration. ;). I think I am using exactly the same example described in the Bundle documentation. Just a *.pdf.twig file being returned with a $this -> render and an array to fill the "gaps" of the template. And always the Pdf annotation. I really don't know what else to check or do :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I got it.

For some reason, the example that comes in the bundle documentation didn't work for me. Nevertheless, there is this class in de bundle: http://github.com/psliwa/PdfBundle/blob/master/Controller/ExampleController.php, where I could find an example that did work for me. This is the code that I finally used:

```
/**
 * @Route ("/generateInvoice", name="_generate_invoice")
 */
public function generateInvoiceAction($name = 'Pedro')
{
    $facade = $this->get('ps_pdf.facade');
    $response = new Response();
    $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Shop:generateInvoiceAction.pdf.twig', array("name" => $name), $response);

    $xml = $response->getContent();

    $content = $facade->render($xml);

    return new Response($content, 200, array('content-type' => 'application/pdf'));
}
```

Next challenge: store that PDF into disk.

Comment: So, what's the case of the PdfBundle official example? Where can I find anything more specific using the @Pdf() annotation and working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't keep researching anything on this... It worked for me and my needs where specific enough to just forget it and go on.

Comment: the only thing to add to the answer is to precise that the root node of the twig template should be `<pdf>`

Answer (score 2):

It's because you've missed the "_format" option in the URL.

`$this->render()` shouldn't be used with the `@Template` annotation. The `@Template` will serve the correct template's format depending of the `_format` parameter.

```
...
use Ps\PdfBundle\Annotation\Pdf;
...

/**
 * @Pdf()
 * @Route ("/pdf.{_format}", name="_pdf")
 * @Template()
 */
public function generateInvoicePDFAction($name = 'Pedro')
{
    return array('name' => $name);
}
```

Should work fine.

Comment: Excellent, thx. How could you know that the bundle does not only rely on the Pdf-Annotation but also on the _format parameter.

Comment: @Greg It's been a long time, I don't remember. Either more rtfm, reverse engeineering or/and some random tries.