# Symfony2 PDF Generator Bundle

Tags: symfony, pdf

I am looking for a PDF generator bundle that is easy to use and that does not require `wkhtmltopdf` as my shared hosting server does not support this.

I have tried `https://github.com/psliwa/PdfBundle`, but if I follow the documentation I simply get a response on the screen (no PDF generated). While there is a solution for this [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655338/symfony2-pdfbundle-not-working), this solution seems overly complex.

I have also looked at `ioalessio/IoTcpdfBundle`, which seems straight-forward enough to use, but does not have a composer install and my web server does not support vendor install.

I have also tried `stedekay/SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle`, but this just plain errors complaining about not finding Java.

While `whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle` might be able to work, this just creates a TCPDF object that one has to work with further and the documentation is not very encompassing.

Any suggestions (or advice on how to get any of the mentioned bundles working) will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use TCPDF library, but you have to give the inline styling to your html elements

Answer (score 4):

I use SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle and I install it from https://github.com/stedekay/SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle using Composer to activate it. I activated in the `AppKernel new Spraed\PDFGeneratorBundle\SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle()`.

Finally I executed the command `php composer.phar update` and in my controller I put this code:

```
 $html = $this->renderView('MyappJournalBundle:Default:index1.html.twig');
    $pdfGenerator = $this->get('spraed.pdf.generator');

    return new Response($pdfGenerator->generatePDF($html),
                    200,
                    array(
                        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
                        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="out.pdf"'
                    )
    );
```

and it worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

I can definitely recommend [KnpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle) with twig templates.

I have used the library/bundle in production several times and haven't had much trouble with it.

( compared to tcpdf & dompdf in legacy applications back then ).

example usage:

```
$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->generateFromHtml(
    $this->renderView(
        'MyBundle:Foo:bar.html.twig',
        array(
            'some'  => $vars
        )
    ),
    '/path/to/the/file.pdf'
);
```

Comment: While the KnpSnappyBundle is the goto bundle for PDF generation, it requires wkpdftohtml, which I cannot use, as stated in my original request.

Comment: Oh sorry speed-reading fail - might be helpful for other users though :D

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of the SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle. My bundle uses a Java library, so you need a working JRE (6 or later) on your server.

Comment: stedekay is it possible to generate canvas elements using spraed?

Comment: I never used canvas elements, but if I understood that correctly, those elements will be drawn by Javascript. So this won't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to install SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle  on Symfony3, make sure the service is:

```
spraed.pdf.generator:
    class: Spraed\PDFGeneratorBundle\PDFGenerator\PDFGenerator
    arguments: [ "@kernel" ]
```

This stands in deep down in the documentation, but its difficult to find.

Another thing you could be aware of is that the generator uses "The Flying Sauser" that uses a special kind of css. So by reading about this, in http://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_36, I found that I had to use: 
@page {  margin: 0 0.5cm; size: 21cm 26.5cm; }
to justify the margins in the document to make the content fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EnseparHtml2pdfBundle.
look [here](https://github.com/devandclick/EnseparHtml2pdfBundle) For more details

Answer (score 0):

You can try this bundle. MpdfPortBundle.
https://github.com/tasmanianfox/MpdfPortBundle

Comment: In this case it's not your fault because the question was off-topic, but please note that in general, an answer that recommends some tool or library must demonstrate how it solves the problem at hand in the answer itself.